# How can I simulate lamp flicker in a Unity shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, algorithm, graphic-effects

I want a game object to keep its brightness (modulating `mainColor`, like `mainColor * brightness`) most of the time, but sometimes make it flicker. Something like a lamp flame that's usually steady, interspersed with short periods of chaotic turbulence before returning to full brightness.

Currently I use `smoothstep(-1,1,sin(frac(_Time.y * _Speed)))` to vary the brightness randomly during the flickering phases, but how can I stop the flickering during the stable phases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out:

```cs
sin(_Time.y) > -0.05 && sin(_Time.y) < 0.05 
    ? smoothstep(-1,1,sin(frac(_Time.y * _Speed))) 
    : 1
```

And then it will multiply `mainColor` to control main color's brightness.